# How to ensure there aren't multiple vertical bounding boxes when performing character segmentation using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

How to make sure there aren't multiple bounding boxes vertically?

Here's the code I'm using to perform character segmentation on an ancient indian scripture:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

img = cv2.imread('/content/0.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 56, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,2))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 56, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,2))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
```

These are the outputs I'm getting (contours/bounding boxes):

[image: contours]

[image: bounding boxes]

My main questions are:

1. How do I make sure that there aren't more than one bounding box vertically so that I can extract the characters?
2. How to fix the issue where there are multiple bounding boxes at the end of the line?

I want my output to be something like this (ms-paint test output):

[image: ms-paint test output]